# Vue setup different vue.config.js configurations for different environments

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a multi-page app that I need some pages to show only in my development environment. This is my vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false,

  pages: {
    index: "src/main.js",
    admin: {
      entry: "src/main-admin.js",
      template: "public/index.html",
      filename: "admin"
    }
  }
};
```

I need the index page to go to my production build, but the admin to be removed from it. Is there a way to add an environment-conditional configuration on vue.config.js, or to add one vue.config.js per environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vue.config.js` is javascript, so you can do pretty much anything you want in there. In your case you could do something like:

```
let config = {
  productionSourceMap: false,
  pages: {
    index: "src/main.js",
  }
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production') {
  config.pages.admin = {
    entry: "src/main-admin.js",
    template: "public/index.html",
    filename: "admin"
  }
}

module.exports = config
```

If you need more environments than the 'builtin' `production`, `development` etc, you can create your own by creating `.env` files, for example a file called `.env.myenv` containing `NODE_ENV=myenv`

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes